# Incrementar HTML com botão em React

Tags: react

Estou fazendo o meu primeiro projeto em React e gostaria de ajuda, pois sou muito iniciante. Gostaria de fazer um botão que adiciona HTML a página. Quando o botão "Add Education" é apertado, novos campos input são adicionados a página. Estou tentando manipular os estados, mas não consigo ter domínio suficiente para incrementar a variável `formEducation` com mais HTML quando o botão é apertado.

Eu sei fazer manipulando o DOM, mas gostaria de fazer manipulando essa variável de estado.

Alguém me da uma luz?

education.js

```
import '../styles/education.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Education(){
    const [formEducation, setFormEducation] = useState(
        <div className="form">
            <div className="input" type="text">
                <label htmlFor="inputInstitution">Instituition name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="inputInstitution" placeholder="Enter the name of your school or university" required></input>
            </div>
            <div className="input">
                <label htmlFor="inputCourse">Course Name: </label>
                <input name="inputCourse" type="text" placeholder="Enter the name of your course" required></input>
            </div>
            <div className="input">
                <label htmlFor="dateInput">Date of conclusion: </label>
                <input name="dateInput" type="date" required></input>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    function Append(){
        
    }
    return (
        <div className="background" id="education">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            { formEducation }
            <button type="button" onClick={ Append }>Add Education</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Education;
```

[Veja a página rodando no navegador aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/digiA.png)

Comment: ao que me parece você está tentando usar o react como jquery, o react é declarativo então o seu formulário já deveria existir no seu jsx, e o estado seria usado somente para saber se deve exibir ele ou não

Comment: seria +- assim

```
function Education(){
    const [formEducation, setFormEducation] = useState(false);
    return (<>
{formEducation && <div>...inputs...</div> }
<button type="button" onClick={ e=>setFormEducation(s=>!s) }>Add Education</button>
     </>);
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No React, é comum manipular estados com tipos de dados primitivos, como números, strings e booleanos, em vez de armazenar HTML diretamente. Armazenar HTML no estado pode dificultar o gerenciamento e a leitura do código.

Então ao usar um número como estado, nós podemos facilmente incrementar ou decrementar o valor e renderizar o número apropriado de componentes ou elementos com base nesse valor. Isso torna seu código mais limpo, modular e fácil de entender.

Seguindo essa lógica podemos criar um estado chamado **formCount**, que armazenará a quantidade de formulários a serem renderizados.

```
const [formCount, setFormCount] = useState(1);
```

Nossa função de **Append** ficaria assim:

```
function appendForm() {
 setFormCount(formCount + 1);
}
```

Podemos usar a função **Array.from()** e **map()** para renderizar a quantidade correta de formulários com base no estado **formCount**:

```
{Array.from({ length: formCount }).map((_, index) => (
 <div key={index} className="form">
  {/* Seu código do formulário aqui */}
 </div>
))}
```

Nosso **Education** ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/education.css';

function Education() {
  const [formCount, setFormCount] = useState(1);

  function appendForm() {
    setFormCount(formCount + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="background" id="education">
      <h2>Education</h2>
      {Array.from({ length: formCount }).map((_, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="form">
          {/* Seu código do formulário aqui */}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={appendForm}>Add Education</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Education;
```

Dessa forma, futuras implementações se tornam mais tranquilas, como criar uma função para remover um formulário pelo índice, por exemplo.

Outra sugestão é utilizar bibliotecas populares, como o [React-Hook-Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) ou [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview), para lidar com formulários mais complexos. Essas bibliotecas facilitam a validação, manipulação e submissão de formulários no React.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede?cb=1